# How to tell MATLAB uigetfile (uigetdir) to default to Windows libraries?

Tags: windows, matlab

Let's assume that I want to select all the `mp3` files in a users `Music` library.  I can access this library from Windows Explorer by typing `libraries\Music` into the path bar (address bar?).  However in MATLAB if I try this with `uigetfile` or `uigetdir` it is not found and the default location is opened instead.

```
[fileName, pathName, ~] = uigetfile('*.mp3', 'Select Song','libraries\Music\');
```

According to this [superuser question](https://superuser.com/questions/240942/environment-variables-for-windows-built-in-libraries), the library is a Windows XML feature and not actually an environment variable.  The suggestion there is to have users create environment variables.  While my users could do that, I don't want to be IT support for the work group so I want a way to do this entirely from the app itself.  I can't rely on hardcoded paths either, as some users have small hard drives and their libraries are pointed to network storage.

Microsoft provides [this description using IShellLibrary.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd758094(v=vs.85).aspx)  But I didn't find any information on using IShellLibrary within MATLAB.  The default file window that opens has the libraries on the left-hand toolbar so it's not a big deal to have the user just select their documents or whatever.  But it's not that clean.

Is there a way for MATLAB to recognize the user's Windows library location?

Comment: It's likely possible to read-out what directories are accessed by the library 'folders'. 'folders' as they're not really folder-containers as we know them, rather a 'redirect' or a 'meta-folder'. You should be able to load the files directly from source locations afterwards. Would that be what you want?

Comment: @user2305193 That sounds like a useful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to get the values for the files from the Windows registry.  The command in MATLAB is `winqueryreg`.  The key to read is `'HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\Personal'`

So the complete command to make this happen is:

```
ext = '*xlsx'; % search for excel for example
title = 'Find Excel in Documents';
locDir = winqueryreg('HKEY_CURRENT_USER',...
    'Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders\', 'Personal');
[file,path,indx] = uigetfile(fullfile(locDir, ext), title);
```